# Django & modelChoiceFields : populate my model choice field with one of two models

Tags: django, choicefield, modelchoicefield

I have a modelChoiceField `field1`, when I Choose one of its choices, another modelChoiceField `field2`  is updated with data.
My problem is, this data can be a `model1` type data or `model2` type data.
and since I have this :

```
field2=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=model1.objects)
```

the `field2` can't be validated if it receives `model2` , it's only valid if it receives `model1`.

Any help please to make my field valid in both cases ?
Thank You for your help